# Understanding the given code

Tags: c, x86

I will appreciate if anyone assists me in understanding the following piece of code
thank you

```
if (iins->uInstr.mnemonic == UD_Ipop)
    regsUsed = (regsUsed & ~(LYNX_ESP | LYNX_SP));
```

Comment: What, exactly, do you not understand?

Comment: the second statement !what exactly is it doing in regsUsed ! and whts with the tilde sign ?

Comment: The code can be simplified: `regsUsed &= ~(LYNX_ESP | LYNX_SP);` to the OP: look up the tilde sign in your syntax chart (probably under "bitwise operators" or "assigment operators")

Comment: @wildplasser, to simplify one has to understand indeed ;-)

Comment: The same goes for | + - ^ (but not for << and >> )

Comment: Please revise your question title so it will be helpful to future visitors. Otherwise it may be closed as Too Localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the mnemonic is `UD_Ipop` then the `LYNX_ESP` and `LYNX_SP` registers aren't used.

A bit more:
`LYNX_ESP` and `LYNX_SP` will have values that have only one bit set. Let's say `LYNX_ESP` is `0x01` and `LYNX_SP` is `0x02`.

```
(LYNX_ESP | LYNX_SP) -> (0x01 | 0x02) -> 0x03  (00000011b)
~(LYNX_ESP | LYNX_SP) -> 0xfc                  (11111100b)

regsUsed can be anything; ????????b
(regsUsed & ~(LYNX_ESP | LYNX_SP)) -> (????????b & 11111100b) -> ??????00b
```

So it turns off the bits representing `LYNX_ESP` and `LYNX_SP` in `regsUsed` and keeps the other bits as they were.

Comment: That's inferring a lot of meaning from the variable names. ;)

Comment: @Autopulated My AI Inference Engine was working overtime. Almost melted my CPU

Answer (score 2):

The second line is equivalent to `regUsed &= ~(LYNX_ESP | LYNX_SP);` (and I can hardly imagine why anybody would write it as it was).

Presumably LYNX_ESP and LYNX_SP are values with (probably) a single bit set in each, something like:

```
LYNX_EAX 1    ; 00000001b
LYNX_EBX 2    ; 00000010b
LYNX_ECX 4    ; 00000100b
; ...
LYNX_SP 64    ; 01000000b
LYNX_ESP 128  ; 10000000b
```

`Or`ing those (`(LYNX_SP | LYNX_ESP)`) gives a value with both bits set. Doing a bit-wise `not` on that (`~`) inverts all the bits so those two bits will be clear, and all the others will be set. It then does a bit-wise `and` between the resulting value and the current value of `regsUsed`, which clears those two bits, and leaves all the other bits unchanged.

Looking at it from a higher level, I'd guess it's using negative (active low) logic -- i.e., a bit being clear in `regsUsed` indicates that a register *is* in use. At this higher perspective, it's basically saying that a `pop` instruction like `pop ebx` not only uses `EBX`, but *also* uses `SP`/`ESP`.

As to why you'd care: this is the sort of thing a CPU does to determine when/whether it can execute instructions in parallel. For example, if you had something like:

```
pop ecx
pop ebx
pop eax
```

It's not (necessarily) immediately apparent that you can't easily execute all three of these in parallel. Each writes to a different register, *but* all three depend on and modify the values in `SP`/`ESP` -- and the code you have above seems to be devoted to extracting/tracking this dependency.

Answer (score 0):

'if the ulnstr.mneminic is equal to UD_lpop then clear in regsUsed all bits that is set to one in LYNX_ESP and/or in LYNX_SP'

Answer (score 0):

The code is doing bitwise math in order to set certain flags. Instead of quickly writing an insufficient explanation here, I will link you to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13740/The-Beginner-s-Guide-to-Using-Enum-Flags), which explains what is going on.